# Post a marker on Google Maps with Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm making an Android app and I want to be able to post a marker onto Google Maps. I'm able to place a marker on Maps but I want it so that the marker is being saved on a server so other clients can see the marker that has just been placed.

How would I be able to do this? Is Endpoints the right tool to use? And finally, are there any good video tutorials on Endpoints with Maps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Endpoints is just a convenient restful API. How you implement it is up to you.

Here is a possible solution:

To add a marker to a map you just need the latitude and longitude inside of a `LatLng` object in Android. To get a latitude and longitude of a device, you need to use the location api. Good place to start: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Once you get that lat and long you can easily store it in an Entity and save that to datastore with Cloud Endpoints. Your other apps can then call an Endpoints method to grab that entity, grab the lat and long, and place the marker on their map.

Endpoints and Maps are two different things but the above is how one could use them together.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't really sure how to tackle this, but this is wonderful. 

I just have one last thing to add; one of my colleagues recommended I should use Google's "My Maps" as an easier solution. What do you think of this?

Comment: @xavvy Unless there is something I don't know, I don't see how Google's My Maps would even apply to making an Android app... You could use My Maps on it's own, but as for integrating it with Android I don't think that is possible...

Comment: Yeaah... I just finished reading up on it and I couldn't really find an API or something. Seems more like a tool on it's own. Thanks again!